# how do i store image paths in an array using vuejs

Tags: frontend, vuejs3

I'm trying to create a slideshow in vuejs to display some images on the homepage and i want to store the images in an array and have the user click next and previous button to be able to scroll through them.

When I use the slideshow component in my homepage, I get an error in the console saying require is not defined.
here is the code :

```
`imagePaths: [
require('../assets/img/classroom.jpg'),
require('../assets/img/childstudying.jpg'), 
require('../assets/img/parentnchildlookingatlaptop.jpg'),
],`
```

Comment: are you using webpack or vite?